# Limit of a Multivariable Function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)} \left(1+x \right)^{y/x}$$

Let $x = \frac{1}{t}$. Then as $x \to 0$, $t \to \infty$, and therefore the limit becomes

$$\lim_{(t,y) \to (\infty, 2)} \left(1+\frac{1}{t} \right)^{ty} = \lim_{(t,y) \to (\infty, 2)} \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{t} \right)^t \right]^y$$

Now, I am not even sure if "$(t,y) \to (\infty,2)$" makes any sense. I know that $\left(1+\frac{1}{t} \right)^t \to e$ as $t \to \infty$, and so I suspect the answer would be $e^2$, since the power function $g(y) = a^y$ is continuous, where $a$ is some constant.

I checked with Wolfram and this is indeed the answer. However, as you may guess form the tone of my writing, I am not very confident in my method of arriving at the answer. I am hoping someone would guide in arriving at the solution rigorously.

Comment: just check sufficient condition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition

Comment: Note the function is not defined anywhere on the $y$-axis. Off the $y$-axis it is defined for any $(x,y)$ with $x>-1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for $y>0:$

$$e^y-\frac{ye^yx}2<\left[\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}\right]^y<\begin{cases}e^y,&x>0\\e^y-2(e^y-2^{y/2})x,&-0.5<x<0\end{cases}$$

So the limit follows nicely through a squeeze.

---

Remarks:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^y,&x=0\\(1+x)^{y/x},&x\ne0\end{cases}$ is convex for all $x>-1$ and $y>0$, so:

$$f(0)+f'(0)x\le f(x)\le f(0)+\frac{f(0)-f(-0.5)}{0-(-0.5)}x$$

which holds for $-0.5<x<0$.

$\left[\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}\right]^y<e^y:$ comes from $(1+x)^{1/x}<e\forall x>0$ is well known.